# Matplotlib print values on bars in subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Using the above code, I have created 5 five subplots:

```
values = {"x_values" : ["ENN", "CNN", "ENN-CNN"],
"eu" : [11, 79.97, 91],
"man" : [11, 80, 90],
"min3" : [11, 79.70, 90],
"min4" : [11, 79.50, 90],
"che" : [12, 78, 89]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=values)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(10,6))

eu = axs[0, 0].bar(df["x_values"], df["eu"]
man = axs[0, 1].bar(df["x_values"], df["man"])
min3 = axs[0, 2].bar(df["x_values"], df["min3"])
min4 = axs[1, 0].bar(df["x_values"], df["min4"])
che = axs[1, 1].bar(df["x_values"], df["che"])
fig.delaxes(axs[1, 2])
```

They print as they should, but I also want to add to the bars the y value of every bar. Just like in the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QDFf.png)

I have tried the code below, but it doesn't print anything, no error but also no print

```
for index, value in enumerate(df["corresponding_df"]):
    plt.text(value, index, str(value))
```

If I try `variable-name.text(value, index, str(value))` I get error `'BarContainer' object has no attribute 'text'`. If `fig.text` again not print. If `axs[subplot-index].text` I can only see a number at the end of the window outside the plots. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using bar_label in matplotlib 3.4.0+:

```
values = {"x_values" : ["ENN", "CNN", "ENN-CNN"],
"eu" : [11, 79.97, 91],
"man" : [11, 80, 90],
"min3" : [11, 79.70, 90],
"min4" : [11, 79.50, 90],
"che" : [12, 78, 89]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=values)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(10,6))

eu = axs[0, 0].bar(df["x_values"], df["eu"])
axs[0,0].bar_label(eu)
man = axs[0, 1].bar(df["x_values"], df["man"])
axs[0,1].bar_label(man)
min3 = axs[0, 2].bar(df["x_values"], df["min3"])
axs[0,2].bar_label(min3)
min4 = axs[1, 0].bar(df["x_values"], df["min4"])
axs[1,0].bar_label(min4)
che = axs[1, 1].bar(df["x_values"], df["che"])
axs[1,1].bar_label(che)
fig.delaxes(axs[1, 2])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Finally, thank you so much. I also tried bar_label but maybe I was using it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

with texts it can be done like this:

```
for ax in axs.flatten():
    for bar in ax.patches:
        ax.text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2, 
                bar.get_height()-7,
                bar.get_height(), 
                ha='center',
                color='w')
```

[image]

Comment: Thats also really nice, thanks for the recommendation.